# How come Java can allocate more memory than the specified heap size

Tags: java, jruby

We are basically tuning our JVM options.

> -J-Xms1536M -J-Xmx1536M -J-Xss3M -J-Djruby.memory.max=1536M -J-Djruby.thread.pool.enabled=true -J-Djruby.compile.mode=FORCE -J-XX:NewRatio=3 -J-XX:NewSize=256M -J-XX:MaxNewSize=256M -J-XX:+UseParNewGC -J-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -J-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -J-XX:SurvivorRatio=5 -J-server -J-Xloggc:/home/deploy/gcLog/gc.log -J-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -J-XX:+PrintGCDetails -J-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -J-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics -J-XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1

We have set the `-J-Xmx1536` and `-J-Xms1536M` to a value of 1536M. Now
If I understood this correctly -J-Xmx represent the maximum size of the heap.

The system is 4 core 15GB ram process.

But when I check the RSS(using top) of my running Java process I see it is consuming a value larger than the `-JXmx1536` around `~2GB`.

Now clearly, the JVM heap has increased beyond the specified value of `-Jmx`.

So my question are..

- Why? am I not seeing any Java out of memory exception.
- And what is an ideal setting for `-JXmx` with 4 cores and 15GB RAM.(given that no other process is running in the system other than Java application)

Comment: Because the *heap* is not the only pool of memory used by the JVM. There is also the JVM internal memory, and the thread stacks, and likely more.

Comment: If your machine has 15GB, why did you only assign 1.5GB to Java? How much is ideal? Depends on your application.

Comment: @Andreas Like I said we were testing the JVM options ... and our initial testing we found that number to fit our need but it seems now that, on a long run that value would be quite less compared to the available RAM we have. Hence the 2nd question.

Answer (score 0):

> Why? am I not seeing any Java out of memory exception.

because you did not run out of heap memory, start VisualVM and examine the process after setting -Xmx. you'll notice there'sa region called MetaSpace (1G max by default) besides that there are also ways in which the process might use additional memory e.g. for code-cache (JIT-ed native code)

> And what is an ideal setting for -JXmx with 4 cores and 15GB RAM.(given that no other process is running in the system other than Java application)

there's no "clear" answer for that, it depends from application to application, you should monitor your memory usage under various scenarios. first thing to do might be to set heap high but if you're not using up most of it and you have a memory leak it will complicate things.